# ¿Es posibles abrir varios archivos.cpp independientes en Visual Studio Community 2019?

Tags: c++

-Deseo crear archivos .cpp independientes para practicar c++ , ejem variables.cpp, cadenas.cpp, funciones.cpp . Pero siempre al querer compilar me pide que asocie del debug con un proceso. Y no hay forma de hacer correr mis ejemplos

-Pero cuando creo un solo proyecto y un archivo cpp que contenga el main(). No hay problema.
-En Visual Studio es OBLIGATORIO crear u proyecto y UN SOLO cpp
que tenga la funcion principal main()?

Comment: No, puedes crear tantos cpp como necesites, pero debes incluirlos en el proyecto para que los compile todos juntos. Primero creas el proyecto, y luego añades ficheros al proyecto.

Comment: pense que era como dev-c++, o codeblock , donde si se puede , tener varias e independientes cada uno con su funcion main().

Comment: Si yo agrego todos dentro del proyecto solo uno de esos cpp , debe tener el main() , yo quiero practicar varios al mismo tiempo. recien comienzo con c++. Luego hare mis proyectos de forma formal

Comment: Pues entonces tienes que crear un proyecto para cada programa. Se supone que un proyecto es para eso, para un módulo: programa, dll, o lo que sea. Pero cuando creas el primer proyecto, creas también lo que se llama Solución. Y en esa solución es donde metes tu proyecto o proyectos. Puedes añadir otro proyecto y compilarlo a parte y cada uno tendrá su main y todos estarán en la misma solución. Al abrir el fichero sln te abrirá todos los proyectos.

Comment: Es más. Cuando creas un proyecto indicas de qué tipo es: De consola, programa windows, dll, etc. Si eliges uno de Consola te creará la estructura básica con un main. Y ahí tú añades al proyecto todos los cpp y h que quieras. Cuando compiles el proyecto, te compilará todos los cpp que tengas incluidos.